# Very Basic Circular motion question

Tags: orbital-motion

[image][image]I was asked to draw a diagram of the forces acting on a ball in vertical circular motion when it is at a horizontal point.

I drew the weight of the ball acting straight down and the centripetal force acting horizontally towards the centre of the circle. The marking scheme included a third force the'reaction' acting vertically upwards. My questiong is where is this third force coming from? (I know it has velocity upwards but i don't see how this could be considered a force

Comment: Can you draw a diagram and add to this question? And be clearer in what the mark scheme shows? From your description here you are perfectly right in what you did - there is no such 3rd force unless the question is missing information.

Comment: By the way, what exactly is a "horizontal point"?

Comment: I added pictures of the question and marking scheme

Comment: The key point that you missed is the work "uniform" in describing the motion.With your free body diagram will the motion have constant speed or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The picture of the man shows it.

- Was it a ball on a string, then only pulling in the string is possible - no lifting. Then only a force towards the center (the **pulling force**) and **gravity** are present.
- In this case, though, the person clearly *lifts* the ball. He *pushes* it upwards. Therefor we have an upwards **pushing force** as well.